# What are some approaches to this implementation challenge from the BIO?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm preparing for the British Informatics Olympiad by solving as many programming problems as I can, and I've stumbled upon one  that seems currently above me. This was the 2014 Round 1 paper. Go to [Question 2](http://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2014/bio/bio14-exam.pdf)

I'm struggling to find a way to put this into code. My first thought was to simply use brute force- i.e.. highlighting the different ways tiles can legally match up, but this seems inefficient,its a 3 hour paper in which I have to solve two other problems, and plus I could miss out on some combinations.

Generally, other than an implementation problem, what other category does this problem fall under? What are some useful tips and stuff I should read on for tacking problems similar like this in the future? I really feel out of my depth here, as I've never tackled anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really give a general hint to what kind of problem this can be treated as, but below is a proposal of how to tackle it.

---

I'll describe this only for scoring of the red player (solid lines), as scoring for green player can be performed analogously. This way is perhaps not the most elegant, but for a 3h time limit, anything that works, right. I'll only cover the 25 mark part (2a).

Each of the 6 tile types can be described as different type of line outlets in the set {north, west, south, east}, say, {n, w, s, e}. Each tile types is described exactly by two of these outlets.

```
Tile 1: {n, s}
Tile 2: {e, w}
... and so on
```

The method to count possible loops would be to, for any given tile, track outlets and see if they return to this given tile. This could be done by starting in top left tile:

1. Choose tile T (initially top left). Follow any of the two outlets to next tile. If you hit a wall, abort and remove tile T from remaining tiles to be examined, and pick next tile, and repeat.
2. For next tile, check if the outlet for previous tile is a matching pair ('n' of T with 's' of new tile, etc)of any of the outlets for the current tile. If not, abort and remove tile T from remaining tiles to be examined, and pick next tile, and repeat.
3. If we're not yet aborted, we've found a matching outlet. Follow the remaining outlet of the new tile and repeat from 1. until:
   3a. We manage to return to starting tile T and match remaining outlet of T with the last tile --> count length of loop.
   3a. We abort prior to this, or return to tile T but won't match last outlet.
4. After T has been covered (counted or cast away), repeat for next tile and repeat the procedure, however treating already covered tiles as walls. Repeat until all tiles have been processed.

Repeat for green player (dashed lines). Good luck with the olympiad!

Answer (score 0):

For 2(a):

Initialize an NxN grid of counters, each set to 2. For convenience, you can extend to a (N+2)x(N+2) grid with sentinel outlines having a null counter.

Scan the grid in search of a nonzero counter.

When you find one, start a loop-following process: decrease the counter of this cell and choose a neighbor with a nonzero counter (it there aren't, skip this cell). Then move to the cell that ensures continuity of the path (knowing the cell code, you determine the exit side from the entrance side). After a while you will meet either the initial cell (you found a loop) or a zero counter (you found an open path).

If all entry/exit links were of the same color, accumulate the number of cells of the loop for this color.

You will repeat a full grid scan twice. In the end all counters are zero.

You will need a "big" decision table that says, for a tile of any type, having a neighbor in one of the four cardinal directions and neighbor being of a given type, what is the next direction to be taken (6x4x6 = 144 entries).